# How can I kill a process when a specific string is seen on standard error?

Tags: bash, grep, stderr

I need to start a process, lets say `foo`. I would like to see the stdout/stderr as normal, but `grep` the stderr for string `bar`. Once `bar` is found in the 
stderr `foo` should be killed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tom Anderson’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14094251) is quite good, but the `kill $(cat $PIDFILE)` will only happen on my system if `foo` terminated on its own, or through Ctrl-C. The following solution works for me

```sh
while read g
do
  if [[ $g =~ bar ]]
  then
    kill $!
  fi
done < <(
  exec foo 2> >(tee /dev/tty)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

*I initially wrote a way to do this that involved stream swizzling, but it wasn't very good. Some of the comments relate to that version. Check the history if you're curious.*

Here's a way to do this:

```
(PIDFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/foo.XXXXXX) && trap "rm $PIDFILE" 0 \
   && { foo \
           2> >(tee >(grep -q bar && kill $(cat $PIDFILE)) >&2) \
        & PID=$! && echo $PID >$PIDFILE ; wait $PID || true; })
```

Good old-fashioned nightmare fuel. What's happening here?

1. The outermost parentheses put the whole thing in a subshell; this constrains the scope of variables, for purposes of hygeine
2. We create a temporary file, using a syntax which works with both GNU and BSD `mktemp`, and call it `PIDFILE`
3. We set up a catch-all exit trap (which runs when the outermost subshell exits) to remove the file named by `PIDFILE`, again for hygeine
4. We run `foo`; this is done in a compound statement so that `&` binds to `foo` and not to the whole preceding pipeline
5. We redirect `foo`'s standard error into a process substitution which waits for `bar` to appear and then kills `foo` (of which more later)
6. We capture `foo`'s PID into a variable, write it to the file named by `PIDFILE`, then wait for it, so that the whole command waits for `foo` to exit before itself exiting; the `|| true` discards the error exit status of `foo` when that happens.

The code inside the process substitution works as follows:

1. First, `tee` the input (`foo`'s standard error), redirecting `tee`'s standard output to standard error, so that `foo`'s standard error does indeed appear on standard error
2. Send the copy of the input going to a file going to another process substitution ([a process substitution *within* a process substitution](http://inception.davepedu.com/))
3. Within the deeper process substitution, firstly run `grep -q` on the input, which looks for the specified pattern, and exits as soon as it finds it (or when it reaches the end of the stream), without printing anything, after which (if it found the string and exited successfully) the shell goes on to ...
4. `kill` the process whose PID is captured in the file named by `PIDFILE`, namely `foo`

Comment: My thinking is that there is a better way to do this that puts the `grep && kill` inside a process substitution which gets `2>` from foo; that leaves `foo`'s streams unswizzled and would be generally simpler.

Comment: @Dolda2000: With `-q`, `grep` *does* exit after finding the first matching line.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Expect to Monitor Standard Error

Expect is designed for taking actions based on output from a process. The simplest solution is to simply let Expect start the process, then exit when it sees the expected output. For example:

```
expect -c 'set msg {Saw "foo" on stderr. Exiting process.}
           spawn /bin/bash -c "echo foo >&2; sleep 10"
           expect "foo" { puts $msg; exit }'
```

If the spawned process ends normally (e.g. before "foo" is seen), then the Expect script will exit, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to the other answer, one way would be to use bash's `coproc` facility:

```
{coproc FOO { foo; } 2>&1 1>&3; } 3>&1
CHILD=$!
while read line <&${FOO[0]}; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q bar; then
        kill $CHILD
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

That's clearly bash-specific, though.

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to figure out a way to do this without PID files or co-routines and in a way that should work in all POSIX-compatible shells (I've tried `bash` and `dash`). At least on systems that support `/dev/fd/`, but that should be pretty much all of them.

It is a bit convoluted, though, so I'm not sure if it is to your liking.

```
(                               # A
    (                           # B
        ( /tmp/foo 2>&1 1>&3 & echo $! >&4 ) |              # C
        ( tee /dev/fd/2 | ( grep -q bar && echo fin >&4 ) ) # D and E
    ) 4>&1 | (                  # F
        read CHILD
        read STATUS
        if [ "$STATUS" = fin ]; then
            kill $CHILD
        fi
    )
) 3>&1
```

To explain the numerous subshells used herein:

The body of `A` runs with the normal stdout duplicated to fd 3. It runs the subshells `B` and `F` with the stdout of `B` piped to the stdin of `F`.

The body of `B` runs with the pipe from `A` duplicated on fd 4.

`C` runs your actual foo command, with its stderr connected to a pipe from `C` to `D` and its stdout duplicated from fd 3; that is, restored to the global stdout. It then writes the PID of `foo` to fd 4; that is, to the pipe that subshell `F` has on its stdin.

`D` runs a `tee` command receiving, from the pipe, whatever `foo` prints on its stderr. It copies that output to both `/dev/fd/2` (in order to have it displayed on the global stderr) and to a pipe connected to subshell `E`.

`E` greps for bar and then, when found, writes `fin` on fd 4, that is, to the pipe that `F` has on its stdin. Note the `&&`, making sure that no `fin` is written if grep encounters EOF without having found `bar`.

`F`, then, reads the PID from `C` and the `fin` terminator from `E`. If the `fin` terminator was properly output, it kills `foo`.

**EDIT**: Fixed the missing `tee` to copy foo's stderr to the real stderr.

Comment: I really don't think that should matter, though. This should work on anything POSIX-compliant, if I'm not mistaken about something.

Comment: Could it be, perhaps, that your `foo` program buffers its stderr when it is connected to a pipe without flushing it?

Comment: Well yes, that is to be expected. `read STATUS` is where `F` waits for grep to find `bar`. You don't have to remove your old comments, by the way. :)

Comment: If I were in your position, I would debug it by strace'ing the various processes involved, but unfortunately, I can't reproduce it.